# How to use functions to put variables into categories

Tags: r

I have a vector of the magnitude of earthquakes in a dataframe, let's say

```
Mag <- c(3, 3.4, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 5, 4, 3.5)
```

How would I use a for loop and `elseif` function to put them in groups 3-3.5,3.5-4,4+

```
## Query2020 is the dataframe I'm using. 

query2020$magVar <- NULL

for (i in 1:length(query2020$mag)) {
  if (query2020$mag[i] < 3.5) {
    query2020$magVar <- 1
  }
  else if (query2020$mag[i] > 3.50 & query2020$mag[i] < 4.00) {
    query2020$magVar <- 2
    else {
      query2020$magVar <- 3
    }
  }
```

I did something like this but my new variable MagVar contains all 3's.

Comment: R vectorizes, so you don't need a for loop. The `dplyr` function `case_when()` is most handy here: `dplyr::case_when(query2020$mag < 3.5 ~ "3-3.5", query2020$mag < 4 ~ "4-4.5", query2020$mag >= 4 ~ "4+")`

Comment: I want to know how it would be done using loops, and what's wrong with my code.  however thanks Phil for the insight!

Comment: Well, there are quite a few errors in your code as shown here, but the most salient one is that you're not storing the output into the `i`th element of the new vector. Wherever you call `query2020$magVar`, it should be `query2020$magVar[i]`.

Comment: @AndyyHu If you would write more clearly, you might have noticed that, among others, `else` is in `else if`. I helped you a little.

Answer (score 1):

The function `cut()` handles this easily:

```
breaks <- seq(2.5, 5, by=.5)
Mag.grp <- cut(Mag, breaks)
Mag.tbl <- table(Mag.grp)
Mag.tbl
Mag.grp
# (2.5,3] (3,3.5] (3.5,4] (4,4.5] (4.5,5] 
#       1       2       4       0       1
```

As the manual page at `?cut` notes, `(2.5,3]` means greater than 2.5 and less than or equal to 3.